# Help Dual Booting Windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, boot, dual-boot, grub2, boot-repair

I am experiencing difficulties to dual boot y HP laptop.
I have installed Windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.04 by allocating free memory to Ubuntu.
Now I cannot boot to Ubuntu.
Upon startup, Ubuntu is unable to boot and i am straight away booted into Windows 8.
I tried EasyBCD, but it did not work.
I have also tried Boot Repair and got the following result: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6006294/
Please help as i am unable to boot to ubuntu.
I have a genuine windows 8, so want to enjoy Ubuntu alongside Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have disabled the Secure Boot feature of UEFI. 
This page describes how to do it: 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#SecureBoot

Comment: line 557 of the Boot-Info indicates that SecureBoot is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that the GRUB menu does not appear, and Windows directly boots.
This may be due to a buggy firmware.

Please:

1. Run `Boot-Repair` --> `Advanced Options` --> tick `Backup and rename Windows EFI files` --> Apply
2. Reboot, the GRUB menu should appear, and let you choose between Ubuntu and Windows.